# R: sum over different columns (difftime)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with several difftimes (fake data):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(q1_begin = dmy_hms("12.02.2021 08:00:00"),
                 q1_end = dmy_hms("12.02.2021 09:00:00"),
                 
                 q2_begin = dmy_hms("12.02.2021 09:00:00"),
                 q2_end = dmy_hms("12.02.2021 09:01:00"),
                 
                 q3_begin = dmy_hms("12.02.2021 09:00:00"),
                 q3_end = dmy_hms("12.02.2021 09:00:10"))

df <- df %>% mutate(time1 = q1_end - q1_begin,
              time2 = q2_end - q2_begin,
              time3 = q3_end - q3_begin)
```

Now I'd like to calculate row-wise the sum of all columns ( = time1 + time2 + time3).
But how can I do this without typing the variable names manually? I've tried:

```r
df %>% mutate(grandTime = sum(starts_with("time"))) # <- Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate(total_time = Reduce(`+`, select(., starts_with('time'))))

# ...    time1  time2   time3 total_time
# ...    hours 1 mins 10 secs  3670 secs
```

Or using data.table:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, total_time := Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols=patterns('time')]
```

Comment: Good one.  Indeed a good usage of reduce. Upvoted